# Restrict Textbox input on keypress based on Regex

Tags: vb.net, validation, input, textbox

I'm attempting to restrict user input via a Regex, but am running into problems when it comes to non-character inputs like backspace and delete.

My original thought was to evaluate what the textbox result would be based on the text and incoming character, then accept the input or prevent it if is passes/fails the regex.  This works until non-character input is reached and then fails on the regex.

Is there a way to evaluate special characters without explicitly checking for each and every one? Or if there is a better way to implement, I'm open to it (I am stuck using the regex for validation).

```
' Regex for double input   ^[+-]?([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]*$

Private Sub txtTestInput_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtTestInput.KeyPress

    If chkValidateOnInput.Checked Then
        Dim part1 As String = txtTestInput.Text.Substring(0, txtTestInput.SelectionStart)
        Dim part2 As String = txtTestInput.Text.Substring(txtTestInput.SelectionStart + txtTestInput.SelectionLength)
        Dim character As String

        character = e.KeyChar.ToString
        Dim result As String = part1 + character + part2

        If Not Regex.IsMatch(result, txtRegex.Text) Then
            e.Handled = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Firstly, why do you have a method with "TextChanged" in the name handling the `KeyPress` event?  That's a great way to cause confusion.  It confused me at first glance.

Comment: As for the issue, it depends what you mean by "special characters".  If you mean control characters then the `Char.IsControl` method should do the job.

Comment: Sorry about that, trying a bunch of stuff, code isn't very clean.  I added `And Not Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar)` to the `If` statement with the regex, and it seems to do the trick.  Will put it through some of my unit tests to verify.